# Change font only for numeral in text mode

Tags: fonts, characters, text-mode

I want to change the font used in 0123456789 to the same as defined in $0123456789$. I know that I can do it to math mode with this command:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{mymathnumerals}{`8}
```

Is there a way to do with text mode?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, it is possible. No, it is not possible. This is also likely engine dependent. For TeX/pdfTeX, you can create a virtual font. However, that is not something you can do in your document and it is quite an involved process if you don't already know much about font management and installation for TeX. Or you could make the characters active, but I imagine that would break your document horribly in other ways.  If you must, just make macros eg. `one` but note, too, that you will lose kerning between numerals and characters in the text font, which will reduce quality.

Comment: what document class and font are you actually using that have different numerals in text and math?  the default for all document classes i see regularly is to use the same numerals in both contexts.